# Si tengo una constante como preguntar el valor de esa constante en un scanner?

Tags: java, java-util-scanner, constantes

Tengo que realizar una cuenta bancaria en la que pregunto cual es el interes anual que esta como constante y el saldo minimo de la cuenta que tambien es constante, si deseo preguntar cual es en un scanner me pide que quite final, como puedo hacer que funcione? 
o deberia agregar el valor que yo deseo directamente en mi clase y mejor dejarme de preguntas?

Comment: Creo que no entendí tu pregunta. ¿Cuál es el punto de preguntar si es constante?. No veo caso de preguntar algo que ya sabes. Deberías de agregar el fragmento de código para analizar un poco mejor la situación y entender tu pregunta.

Comment: pregunto si tengo una constante y la quiero añadir como parametro de un scanner para añadir el valor a mano si se puede de alguna manera, por ejemplo tengo la constante interes  yo en un scanner deseo preguntar al usuario cual sera el valor de esa constante, por ejemplo será 20 para que se le añada 20 a la contante.

Comment: es decir una constante que he declarado pero sin un valor y después al preguntarle al usuario se le añade dicho valor con el scanner.

Comment: A lo que entendí es quitar el final porque estas tratando de asignarle un valor.

Comment: Exacto el programa me decía que debía quitar final de mi constante al tratar de usarla en un scanner debido a que estaba en un bucle y no podia ser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Si tengo una constante como preguntar el valor de esa constante en un scanner?

Simplemente puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```java
public class Program 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        final String op;
        op = sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Lo que debes tomar en cuenta, que al momento de asignarle un valor a la variable constante, ya no podrás alterar su contenido, de lo contrario, el compilador dará un error de compilación.

**Ejemplo del error:**

```java
public class Program 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        final String op;
        op = sc.nextLine();
        op = sc.nextLine();//error
    }
}
```

En el código de arriba dará el siguiente error:

```java
variable op might already have been assigned.
```

Y esto se debe porque estás modificando el contenido de la variable `op`.

> > si deseo preguntar cual es en un scanner me pide que quite final, como puedo hacer que funcione?

Si se puede preguntar al usuario que valor quiere que tenga la variable constante, sin embargo, el problema radica en la forma como lo estés haciendo.

Por ejemplo, si la variable es constante y lo agregas adentro de un bucle:

```java
public class Program 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        final String op;
        while(true)
        {
            op = sc.nextLine(); //error
        }

    }
}
```

Nos dará otro error de compilación, debido a que, el compilador se dio cuenta que la variable `op` puede ser alterada y es evidente, porque si lo agregas en un bucle, el usuario podrá modificar el contenido de la variable cada vez que quiera.

**Conclusión:**

Si lo que vas a pedir al usuario es únicamente una vez, deberías usar una variable constante, de lo contrario, no debe ser declarada como `final`.

Comment: Vale vale ya lo entiendo, justo tengo la pregunta de mi constante dentro de un do, while por lo tanto da error ya que cada vez que se repita mi bucle volverá a preguntar por el dato y es un valor que solo se coloca una sola vez Gracias!!!! ya entiendo!